# Format data for a graph

Tags: excel

I have the following table

[image]

and I want to create a scatter plot with straight lines and markers. and the way I want to organise the data is

- Have the x axis be the StartTime
- Have the y axis be AvgValue

and then have each SerialNumber be a line within the graph of a different colour and then have the SerialNumber as my legend

The issue here is that I don't know how to format my data to obtain this type of graph, I've tried different things that did not seem to work for me. Can somebody help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reshape your data by using a pivot table. Rows = StartTime, Cols = SerialNumber and Values = AvgValue.

After you create the pivot table, you may need to right-click on one of the dates and select "Ungroup".

Then create a pivot chart off your table. The results aren't pretty because you have many gaps in your dates, but this is effectively what you are asking for, right? You can adjust the format in many ways to make it more appealing, but you are still left with gaps in dates.
[image]